# RAZOR variable in variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi i have a little question about razor ...

I need to send an email with multiple article bought by a client
I made a `for`-loop to generate one line per article.
But each line need to show different name for each product

Example if the client bought 3 articles :

> Line 1 : Article_1
>
> Line 2 : Article_2
>
> Line 3 : Article_3

But actually my loop only shows `Article_1` for each Line

![examle][1]

Anyone know how to replace the "X" according to "i" ?

```
@{
var i = 0;
}

<!-- SOME HTML -->


@for(i=1 ; i < Convert.ToInt32(NB_PRODUCT); i++){
<tr>
    <td>TITLE_X</td>
    <td>PRICE_X</td>
</tr>
}
```

In my database i can have a lot of products to display (each tr = 1 product)

Here an example of database
[image: examle]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, please post your model code and razor view code, no code screenshots please

Comment: You need to include the code

Comment: Your articles should be held in lists, e.g. `List<ArticleModel>` and you can easily iterate through Articles using `@foreach ...` method. If you named your Properties `Article_1`, `Article_2` etc., you're doing it wrong and will always have a hard time accessing the properties without using  dynamic/reflection or other "magic"

Comment: Edited with code

Comment: OK; now the View is quite clear, now how does the Model look like? Where are the Articles?

Comment: Edited with a screen with an example of database :)

Answer (score 0):

You must load the data from your database in your controller or model, into objects like lists (or arrays) first.

Then once you have a list or array you can actually go through it in the HTML.
your code should look *kinda* like this (note: not literally):

you should provide the code where you read your DB, so lets just asume that part

Controller:

```
string[] ArraywithTitles = //your DB data for Titles (the column Article1)
string[] ArraywithPrices = //your DB data for price1
ViewBag.TITLE_X = ArraywithTitles;
ViewBag.PRICE_X = ArraywithPrices;
```

The contents of your array should be (if you were to read them, do not set them manually):

```
ArraywithTitles[0] = "t-shirt";
ArraywithTitles[1] = "t-shirt";
ArraywithTitles[2] = "pants";


//View
@for(i=1 ; i < Convert.ToInt32(NB_PRODUCT); i++){
<tr>
<td>@TITLE_X[i]</td>
<td>@PRICE_X[i]</td>
</tr>
```

now if you want the different articles, you need to have all of them in arrays or lists

```
//note: you must add ifs (or a switch case) for each NB_Product case, 
//this is only for when a client has 3 products
@for(i=1 ; i < Convert.ToInt32(NB_PRODUCT); i++){
<tr>
<td>@Article1[i]</td>
<td>@PRICE1[i]</td>
<td>@Article2[i]</td>
<td>@PRICE2[i]</td>
<td>@Article3[i]</td>
<td>@PRICE3[i]</td>
</tr>
```

if you need further assistance (or a more literal solution), you should provide your controller and model code as well.